# How can I proceed with this exercise?

Tags: complex-analysis, plane-curves

It asks me to graph the region in the complex plane.

$Re(z+iz) \le 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If you write $z=x+yi$, $x$ and $y$ real, you should recognize it.

Comment: You mean $Re(x-y+ix+iy)$?

Comment: @tomm89: That is right.  Then what is the real part?

Comment: $x-y$ problem resolved, thank you!

Comment: @tomm89:  then you could accept the answer by clicking the check mark.  It will keep the problem from being brought back up by the robot

Comment: I tried that, but it said I had to wait 5 min. Then I forgot

Comment: @tomm89:  looks like you got it now.  Thanks